# Deleted images still appear

Tags: wordpress, slider, elementor, custom-wordpress-pages

I utilize the Elementor Pro plugin to upload images for showcasing within a slider on my website. However, I've encountered a perplexing issue: even after deleting certain images and saving the post, they continue to persistently appear within the slider. It's important to note that there is no active caching mechanism or any other relevant factor that could explain this unusual behavior.

The page I need help with: [Slider Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhPM9.jpg)https://nexinfo.com/

I disabled ALL plugins except for WPML and Elementor and still had these problems.

I then disabled Elementor and the only plugins that were active were WPML. I was then able to edit home page AND all the English content that was not displaying, along with all the unsaved changes were in fact there. Reactivating Elementor caused those same above issues.

How to solve?